# SQL Oracle слишком длинный идентификатор

Tags: sql, oracle

Также знаю про размер идентификатора в 30 байтов, и то что кириллица весит 2 байта, но в моей таблице нет и 15 символов в названии.

```
CREATE TABLE insurance_type(
"ID_Видстрах"  NUMBER(2, 0)        NOT NULL,
"Вид страх"    VARCHAR2(8) UNIQUE  NOT NULL,
"Наим риска" VARCHAR2(32) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
constraint ВИД_СТРАХ_PK PRIMARY KEY ("ID_Видстрах"));
```

*[42000][972] ORA-00972: слишком длинный идентификатор*

Подобная ошибка выдается на многие таблицы в которых не присутствует названий длиннее 15 символов с использованием кириллицы. Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести вашу ошибку. Таблица создаётся 1:1 как в вопросе в любой версии. Укажите вашу версию, кодировку и семантику длины символов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все идентифкаторы с длинной более 30 английских символов, а также любые содержащие не английские буквы должны заключаться в двойные кавычки.

Название ключа у вас `ВИД_СТРАХ_PK` без кавычек.

С систаксисом  ниже таблица создалась под Oracle 11.

```
CREATE TABLE insurance_type(
"ID_Видстрах"  NUMBER(2, 0)        NOT NULL,
"Вид страх"    VARCHAR2(8) UNIQUE  NOT NULL,
"Наим риска" VARCHAR2(32) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
constraint "ВИД_СТРАХ_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_Видстрах"));
```

Описанное справедливо, если по умолчанию для базы установлен английский алфавит. Судя по документации при определенных условиях даже русские идентифкаторы могут быть без кавычек.

> Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from
>   your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any
>   character

Подробно в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51109).

Comment: Касатекльно имён идентифкаторов, дополните пожалуйста ответ ссылкой на документацию.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! Проверте пожалуйста на соответствие формулировок в ответе к приведённой цитате и документации.